# Download torrent form torcache.com using php.?

Tags: php, python, gzip

As the server is using gzip encription I am getting an error torrent while downloading.

```
<?

$path_parts = pathinfo("http://torcache.com/torrent/56A250DC4CD64F6C304631897F1108D413FE76C7.torrent");
$name= $path_parts['basename'];
$d="torrent/".$name;
if(!copy($f,$d))
{
 echo "not copied";
}
else
{
 echo "copied";
}

?>
```

Then i used this then also the result is invalid torrent

```
<?php

/* Tutorial by AwesomePHP.com -> www.AwesomePHP.com */
/* Function: download remote file */
/* Parameters: $url -> to download | $dir -> where to store file |
    $file_name -> store file as this name - if null, use default*/

/* $path_parts = pathinfo("http://torcache.com/torrent/56A250DC4CD64F6C304631897F1108D413FE76C7.torrent");
$name= $path_parts['basename'];
$d="torrent/".$name; */

$f="http://torcache.com/torrent/56A250DC4CD64F6C304631897F1108D413FE76C7.torrent";

downloadRemoteFile($f,"torrent/",$file_name = NULL);

function downloadRemoteFile($url,$dir,$file_name = NULL){
    if($file_name == NULL){ $file_name = basename($url);}
    $url_stuff = parse_url($url);
    $port = isset($url_stuff['port']) ? $url_stuff['port'] : 80;

    $fp = fsockopen($url_stuff['host'], $port);
    if(!$fp){ return false;}

    $query  = 'GET ' . $url_stuff['path'] . " HTTP/1.0\n";
    $query .= 'Host: ' . $url_stuff['host'];
    $query .= "\n\n";

    fwrite($fp, $query);

    while ($tmp = fread($fp, 8192))   {
        $buffer .= $tmp;
    }

    preg_match('/Content-Length: ([0-9]+)/', $buffer, $parts);
    $file = substr($buffer, - $parts[1]);
    $file_binary=($file);
    if($file_name == NULL){
        $temp = explode(".",$url);
        $file_name = $temp[count($temp)-1];
    }
    $file_open = fopen($dir . "/" . $file_name,'w');

    if(!$file_open){ return false;}
    fwrite($file_open,$file_binary);
    fclose($file_open);
    return true;
} 
?>
```

**python**

```
import urllib2, httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
request = urllib2.Request('http://torcache.com/torrent/4F78CA71DD8C308F18426F845AFBFF4481633B11.torrent')
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(request)
compresseddata = f.read()

import StringIO
compressedstream = StringIO.StringIO(compresseddata)
import gzip
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedstream)
data = gzipper.read()
print data
filename = "633B11.torrent"
FILE = open(filename,"w")
FILE.write(data)
```

Then i used python wiht gzip compression still i am getting invalid torrent file can **anyboy help me to solve the gzip problem in php to download a torrent from a torrent cache server with gzip encoding**

Comment: Gzip is not an *encryption* algorithm, just a *compression* algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, solution is ya just decode the torrent before saving it.simplezz

```
function gzdecode($d){
$f=ord(substr($d,3,1));
$h=10;$e=0;
if($f&4){
    $e=unpack('v',substr($d,10,2));
    $e=$e[1];$h+=2+$e;
}
if($f&8){
    $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
}
if($f&16){
    $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
}
if($f&2){
    $h+=2;
}
$u = gzinflate(substr($d,$h));
if($u===FALSE){
    $u=$d;
}
return $u;}


$torrent = file_get_contents('http://URL_PATH_TO_TORRENT.torrent',FILE_BINARY);


$torrent = gzdecode($torrent);
file_put_contents('./torrentname.torrent',$torrent);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but i am getting ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare gzdecode() in on line 22 which is return $u;}

Answer (score 1):

Took me a lot of time to understand why i can't just download the torrent file using python. The user agent has to be Mozilla :)

```
import requests

url = r"https://torcache.net/torrent/6175754C9A5502BA085F8D64F31C8158AB0BE1C5.torrent?title=[kat.cr]paper.towns.2015.1080p.brrip.x264.yify"

s = requests.Session()

s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0"})

answer = s.get(url)

torrent_data = answer.content

print torrent_data[:100]
```